# Does anyone know what this wood wedge is for? Approx 7" Long

Tags: wood

[image]Does anyone know what this wood wedge is for?

[image: Image1[![][1]]

Comment: Tough to get a sense of scale - how big is this thing? My first thought is that it's a doorstop, but it may be too big for that, and I don't know what that hole would be for.

Comment: Ya that was my first thought - doorstop - but the hole?? It's approx 7" long

Comment: Cantilevered wine bottle holder?  (Like this: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/wCJYWKRgDXE/hqdefault.jpg )

Comment: @SaSSafraS1232, post it as an answer, because I believe you are correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that this is a cantilevered wine bottle holder.  It will rest with the branding down, and the neck of the bottle is inserted into the hole so that the bottle rests horizontally.

Here is a similar design:

[image: Cantilevered wine bottle holder]

Comment: awesome - thx!!

Comment: What are they for? Bottles are usually made to be able to stand on their own.

Comment: @Wilson For display, and for fun.

Comment: @Wilson, they're often bought as gifts, same basic motivation as "executive gifts" and other novelty items. At least that's my impression of them.

Comment: @Wilson, wine corks need to remain wet to keep their seal.  Storing a bottle horizontally accomplishes this.  The wedge does this more artistically than just laying on a shelf in the fridge.

Comment: @B540Glenn So that's where I've been going wrong with my homebrew...